Curating the Intellisense suggestions in LaTeX Workshop on VS Code
TL;DR I want a comprehensive list of the macros Intellisense suggests for LaTeX Workshop on VS Code. Some of them are contained in JSON files in the data directory of the github repository for this VS Code extension, but many are not and I cannot find them.
Intro
Last year I started using VSCode (LaTeX Workshop by James Yu) for developing Latex - writing papers, homework assignments etc. I was excited by the prospect of using Intellisense autosuggestions and other nice features, and pleased to be working with something more customizable than Overleaf.
My problem is that Intellisense suggests far too many macros I never use in “daily driver” conditions. No problem! The item
latex-workshop.intellisense.command.user

can be configured in settings.json to omit autosuggestions. Supposing I had a list of all the macros, I could disable everything and then reactivate them a la carte, ending up with the sleek, parsimonious auto-suggest I desire.
Hidden Macros
Small problem: there are literally hundreds of macros available in autosuggestions. Following the extension’s Wiki, I went into the LaTeX Workshop repository and pulled a variety of JSON files such as commands.json which are supposed to contain all the auto-suggest macros. I pulled this list and inserted it into my latex-workshop.intellisense.command.user configuration and bam, those commands are gone.
On the other hand, while the macros in commands.json have now been disabled, there are hundreds more which are not disabled. For example, commands.json includes macros such as bibitem[]{}, which are successfully disabled, but does not contain macros such as \abovedisplayshortskip.
Ok, so these other macros are stored somewhere else. But big problem: I cannot find a directory containing these “ghost” macros within LaTeX workshop. Where are they? If I knew where these were stored, I could assemble a list of exceptions for the latex-workshop.intellisense.command.user configuration and disable them. But I cannot find them in the LaTeX Workshop repo, and the usual “search” command in my file browser (I run Mac OS) gives nothing.
For posterity, here are my intellisense-relevant settings in VSCode:
{
"editor.suggest.showSnippets": true,
"editor.suggest.showFunctions": true,
"editor.suggest.showReferences": true,
"editor.suggest.showIcons": true, 
"editor.suggest.showInlineDetails": true, 
"editor.suggest.showModules": true, 
"latex-workshop.intellisense.package.enabled": false
"editor.suggest.showUsers": false,
"editor.suggest.showVariables": false,
"editor.suggest.showWords": false,
"editor.suggest.showUnits": false,
"editor.suggest.showValues": false,
"editor.suggest.showTypeParameters": false,
"editor.suggest.showStructs": false,
"editor.suggest.showProperties": false,
"editor.suggest.showOperators": false,
"editor.suggest.showIssues": false,
"editor.suggest.showFolders": false,
"editor.suggest.showFiles": false,
"editor.suggest.showEvents": false,
"editor.suggest.showDeprecated": false,
"editor.suggest.showCustomcolors": false,
"editor.suggest.showClasses": false,
"editor.suggest.showColors": false,
"editor.suggest.showConstants": false,
"editor.suggest.showConstructors": false,
"editor.suggest.showEnums": false,
"editor.suggest.showEnumMembers": false,
"editor.suggest.showFields": false,
"editor.suggest.showInterfaces": false,
"editor.suggest.showKeywords": false,
"editor.suggest.showMethods": false,
"latex-workshop.intellisense.unimathsymbols.enabled": false
}

and here is an example configuration disabling Intellisense autosuggestions for the command \abovedisplayshortskip (this is one of the hundreds of "elusive" macros I cannot find).
"latex-workshop.intellisense.command.user": {
    "abovedisplayshortskip": "",

Some additional comments

I could theoretically disable     "editor.suggest.showFunctions" and replace all macros I want with user-defined snippets but this would eliminate some actually useful macros, including the lovely begin macro which I use frequently and would prefer not to have to replicate.
I have tried deleting and reinstalling LaTeX Workshop. I am currently running LTex  for spell-check and in the past have run LaTeX Utilities, but I doubt either would have dumped without warning hundreds of macros into Intellisense.

